# Modal Page in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, modal-dialog

I've a question about how can I do a Modal Screen in Forms Xamarin like the image that Follows Attached.

I Wanna know if it is possible you guys send me a piece of code or sample to understand how to do it.

https://extravios.com.br/comunicados/Modal.Forms.Xamarin.600.png

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I'd encourage you to make a concrete attempt at achieving what you are trying to do first, as that both demonstrates that you've done the needed background research as well as clarifies your question.

Answer (score 2):

The standard modal in Xamarin.Forms cannot be transparent. You have to create your own view

Answer (score 1):

Insert an absoluteview where you want your modal window!

```
<AbsoluteLayout  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="className">
    <!-- Transparent Background -->
    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                 BackgroundColor="Gray"
                 Opacity="0.5"
                 >
    </StackLayout>

    <!-- Content -->
    <ContentView x:Name="Overlay"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                 BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                 Padding="10, 0">
        <Frame Opacity="1">
           <Label Text="myLabel"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </ContentView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [Navigation.PushModalAsync](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AXamarin.Forms.INavigation.PushModalAsync%28Xamarin.Forms.Page%29)

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task PushModalAsync (Page page)
```